# How to set radeon power low

Tags: power-management, radeon, fancontrol

So I used to be able to do what [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver) recommends for <= 3.10.x and set my radeon power_profile to low, but that seems to no longer work.

For example:

```
sudo bash -c "echo \"profile\" > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method"
bash: line 0: echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

So I tried the newer command by setting `radeon.dpm=1`, but whatever it's doing I don't believe is setting the power usage to "low" because I can hear the difference. (Sounds like mid.)

How can I force the radeon driver to use LOW power profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I tried the newer command by setting radeon.dpm=1, but whatever it's doing I don't believe is setting the power usage to "low" because I can hear the difference. (Sounds like mid.)

Correct, it isn't setting the power usage to low. `radeon.dpm=1` is a kernel parameter that *enables* DPM.

Read up [here](http://www.botchco.com/agd5f/?p=57) to see how exactly DPM works in current kernels.